# apply different discount on car

Tags: java

I am just new to java programming I need help to print out car price after discount have been applied. At the moment it displays the discount amount.

```
public class carApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Car car1 = new Car("Toyota", "2012", 13500.00);
        Car car2 = new Car("Audi", "2011", 12000.00);

        System.out.printf("Car 1 Model: %s; Car year: %s; Car Price: %.2f\n",
                car1.getModel(), car1.getYear(), car1.getcarPrice());

        System.out.printf("Car 1 Model: %s; Car year: %s; Car Price: %.2f\n",
                car2.getModel(), car2.getYear(), car2.getcarPrice());

        System.out.println("Car Price after applying discount");
        car1.setcarPrice(car1.getcarPrice()*(0.05));
        car2.setcarPrice(car2.getcarPrice()*(0.07));

        System.out.printf("Car 1 Model: %s; Car year: %s; Car Price: %.2f\n",
                car1.getModel(), car1.getYear(), car1.getcarPrice());

        System.out.printf("Car 1 Model: %s; Car year: %s; Car Price: %.2f\n",
                car2.getModel(), car2.getYear(), car2.getcarPrice());
    }
}
```

Comment: It displays the discount amount because you're setting the price to `getcarPrice()*(0.05)`, which is 5% of the original price. Or 7% in the other case.

Comment: As @Cinnam said, just multiply by (1-0.05) and (1-0.07) or equally 0.95 and 0.93.

Comment: Echoing Cinnam, to get the price of the car after discount, you need to subtract the discount amount from 1: `getcarPrice()*(1 - 0.05)`

Answer (score 0):

@Mkreegs is right, you should write

```
car1.setcarPrice(car1.getcarPrice()*(1 - 0.05));
car2.setcarPrice(car2.getcarPrice()*(1 - 0.07));
```

or straightaway:

```
car1.setcarPrice(car1.getcarPrice()*(0.95));
car2.setcarPrice(car2.getcarPrice()*(0.93));
```

Comment: Thanks mate i got the solution